# How do I return the Resource ID of a drawable from my app back to a calling app of a different package/developer

Tags: android, image, android-intent, gallery, default

I'm building an app that containts a large number of images for use as alternative icons with any chat client using the image share option.

EDIT: I figured out how to launch my app from another app(Not one of mine) so that now i can choose between the default gallery or my app for selecting images.

What remains is that I need to know what exactly the image gallery returns to apps that call it for image picking so i can return the same thing from my app.

EDIT 3: I am now passing an Intent back to the chat client as so

```
Uri imageURI;
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.eric1 :
        imageURI = Uri.parse(MY_RESOURCE_URI);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageURI);
        shareIntent.setType("image/plain");
        setResult(RESULT_OK, shareIntent);
        Utils.makeToast("Selected",this);
        finish();
```

Now im getting an error that share a file failed. Is it because I am trying to pass a resource URI from my package to another package?

EDIT- Finally solved it this way

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resID);
        File imageFile;
        Date d = new Date();
        int imgName = (Long.toString(d.getTime())).hashCode();
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        printDebug(state);
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            File file = getExternalCacheDir();
            if (file != null) {
                try {
                    //String root = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    imageFile = new File(file, imgName+".png");
                    printDebug(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                    boolean complete = image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
                    if (!complete) {
                        Log.d("tag", "image not saved");
                    }
                    Log.d("tag", "image saved");
                    return Uri.parse(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("tag", "Can't save image", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
        }
```

thanks for the help

Comment: when any app calls your activity with startActivityForResult()..you can result back string "file/path/to/the/image/in/sdcard"

Comment: yeah return the path of the file

Comment: @MKJParekh : I have no idea of what exactly the app i am returning to expects in its onActivityResult method.I'm writing an app similar to the Smileys for chat app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidsx.smileys&hl=en

I have completed everything except the image returning part which is getting really frustrating as even after scouring all over I cant seem to figure out what is to be passed back in the results.

Comment: Thanks for including the complete solution -- you should post it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I forgot to post it as an answer but here it is -

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resID);
    File imageFile;
    Date d = new Date();
    int imgName = (Long.toString(d.getTime())).hashCode();
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    printDebug(state);
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        File file = getExternalCacheDir();
        if (file != null) {
            try {
                //String root = file.getAbsolutePath();
                imageFile = new File(file, imgName+".png");
                printDebug(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                boolean complete = image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
                if (!complete) {
                    Log.d("tag", "image not saved");
                }
                Log.d("tag", "image saved");
                return Uri.parse(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("tag", "Can't save image", e);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
    }
```